# Equivalence test using confidence intervals of the estimated coefficient from a generalized linear model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, equivalence

I intend to determine whether the difference in Y (a measured response variable) between a control and treatment group is smaller than what is considered meaningful (i.e. equivalent), using confidence intervals. I would like to do this with a response variable that is not normally distributed and therefore a generalised linear model has been carried out - e.g. count data with a poisson regression, or using a gamma distribution.

Equivalence can be tested by determining if a confidence interval at the desired level (e.g. 90% CI) of the difference between the two groups means lies within the equivalence boundaries. I understand that if a logistic regression is carried out one can work with the odds ratio to determine equivalence - see this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/368725. Briefly, one can calculate the CI of the odds ratio and determine whether this CI sits within the equivalence boundaries.

**My question is whether a similar method can be used to test equivalence when using a generalised linear model with a different distribution family, i.e. whether the estimated coefficient (slope) can be used to test equivalence**

For example, I have a response variable with a gamma distribution and want to test for equivalence of a control and treatment group. I think that anything within a 2-fold change of Y is not a meaningful difference so I set my equivalence bounds as 0.5 and 2 (equal change in both directions on the log scale). Using a generalised linear model with a distribution family = gamma and link = log I get the estimated coefficient on the log scale for treatment (2 levels: control and treatment). If I exponentiate this estimate I get 1.5 (for example) which means that Y is 1.5-fold higher in the treatment group compared to the control group. I then calculate the exponentiated 90% CI of the estimated coefficient which is 0.6 to 3.5. This CI does not sit completely within the equivalence bounds of 0.5 - 2, it falls out the top end. Therefore, I have not shown equivalence (reject null hypothesis of equivalence). There is evidence that Y in the treatment group can be up to 3.5 fold higher than in the control group.